# Python - How to manipulate FastAPI request headers to be mutable?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I am trying to change my request headers in my api code. Its immutable right now oob with fastapi starlette. how can i change it so my request headers are mutable? i would like to add, remove, and delete request headers. i tried to instantiate a new request and directly modify the request using

```
request.headers["authorization"] = "XXXXXX"
```

but I get the following error

```
TypeError: ‘Headers’ object does not support item assignment
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do something with the header in a middleware. Because FastAPI is Starlette underneath, Starlette has a data structure where the headers can be modified. You can instantiate MutableHeaders with the original header values, modify it, and then set request._headers to the new mutable one. Here is an example below:

```
from starlette.datastructures import MutableHeaders
from fastapi import Request    

@router.get("/test")
def test(request: Request):
     new_header = MutableHeaders(request._headers)
     new_header["xxxxx"]="XXXXX"
     request._headers = new_header
     request.scope.update(headers=request.headers.raw)
     print(request.headers)
     return {}
```

Now you should see "xxxxx" is in the print output of your request.headers object:

```
MutableHeaders({'host': '127.0.0.1:8001', 'user-agent': 'insomnia/2021.5.3', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'authorization': '', 'accept': '*/*', 'content-length': '633', 'xxxxx': 'XXXXX'})
```

Comment: It might be added that this will not update the scope attribute of the Request-object. For that to happen the update member function has to be called `request.scope.update(headers=request.headers.raw)`

Comment: The above response is useless without your suggestion for the ```scope``` update. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't Work.

Comment: Really, author, please, consider adding the @F.Sonntag suggestion to the answer, otherwise it doesn't work...

Comment: This code is written in an odd way. I'd recommend using the mutablecopy() method on request.headers to make the copy: `request.headers.mutablecopy()`. I'd recommend updating the scope FIRST: `request.scope['headers'] = new_header.raw`, then deleting the `_headers` attribute, so it's recreated when request.headers is called: `delattr(request, '_headers')`.