# FastAPI API Versioning - specifying deprecated version in Header

Tags: python, enums, fastapi, api-versioning

I am using a `Header` named `Accept-Version` to handle API versioning in my FastAPI project at the function level. Following [fastapi documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#predefined-values), a sub-class that inherits from `str` and from `Enum` is used to predefine the version that the header can accept.

As the project goes on, I want to mark the old versions as deprecated without removing it. The code is as follows.

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Union
from fastapi import FastAPI, Header
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class VersionNumber(str, Enum):
    _1_1 = "1.1 (deprecated)"
    _1_2 = "1.2"
    _1_3 = "1.3"


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: float


@app.post("/items")
async def update_item(item: Union[Item, None], accept_version: VersionNumber=Header(VersionNumber._1_2)):
    accept_version = accept_version.replace('(deprecated)', '')
    accept_version = float(accept_version)
    if accept_version == 1.1:
        return item
    elif accept_version >= 1.2 and accept_version < 1.3:
        return item.dict()["name"], item.dict()["price"]
    else:
        return item.dict()["name"]
```

Based on the code above, the Swagger UI is able to show version `1.1` as deprecated, which looks like this.

[image]

However, when sending the request, it is accepting `1.1 (deprecated)` instead of `1.1` as a value for `Accept-Version` header, which is not desirable. Is there a way to elegantly mark version `1.1` as deprecated and keep the header as `1.1`?

Comment: As far as I know, you could add a `middleware`, match for the string in the `header` of the `request` and delete it. Could that be an option? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware

Comment: @Isabi Thanks for the suggestion. I believe `middleware` won't help as I am still accepting `1.1 (deprecated)` instead of `1.1` in the `Accept-Version` header?

Comment: Nope, you change the header in the `middleware` and then go on with the normal flow. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934160/python-how-to-manipulate-fastapi-request-headers-to-be-mutable